# How to hide user status messages in XChat?

Tags: xchat

I'm referring to messages like these:

```
yeswanth (~yeswanth@115.184.67.87) has joined #python-dev
```

and

```
yeswanth has quit (Ping timeout: 260 seconds)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Right-click the "channel" tab
- Point to "settings"
- Click on "hide join/part messages"

[image]

Comment: How to do that globally?